# What am I doing wrong? inner product

Tags: hilbert-spaces

The general form of an inner product in $\mathbb{C}^n$ is $\langle x,y\rangle=y^{*}Bx$ where B is a Hermitian positive definite matrix.
Then for any square matrix $A$ we have $\langle Av,w\rangle=w^{*}BAv$ and $\langle v,A^{*}w\rangle=(A^{*}w)^{*}Bv=w^{*}ABv$.

Since for any matrix $A$, it is a fact that $\langle Av,w\rangle=\langle v,A^{*}w\rangle$ then we have 
$w^{*}BAv=\langle Av,w\rangle=\langle v,A^{*}w\rangle=w^{*}ABv$.
But that implies $BA=AB$, which is wrong.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If by $A^\ast$ you denote the conjugate transpose, you only have $\langle Av, w\rangle = \langle v, A^\ast w\rangle$ for all matrices $A$ and vectors $v,w$ if $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is (a multiple of) the standard inner product. For other inner products, the adjoint of $A$ is not the conjugate transpose.

Comment: Then, are you saying that in http://www.math.wisc.edu/~jensen/Algebra/inner.pdf the lemma in the second page is wrong?

Comment: Supposedly, they consider only the standard inner product. But they could also be plain wrong, I haven't looked.

Comment: They assume the inner product is any inner product. This is made clear by the proposition following that lemma where they relate any inner product to the standard inner product.

Comment: Okay, then I will have to take a look. Give e a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

That is because $A^*$ is defined with respect to the standard inner product (that is, when $B=I$). So in your case you do not have $(Ax, y) = (x, A^*y)$.

Answer (score 1):

It's an error in your source.

With an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_B$ given by a (hermitian positive definite) matrix $B$, i.e.

$$\langle v, w\rangle_B = w^\ast\cdot B \cdot v,$$

for any matrix $A$, there is an adjoint matrix $\tilde{A}^B$ such that for all $v, w$ we have

$$\langle Av, w\rangle_B = \langle v, \tilde{A}^B w\rangle_B.$$

Written out,

$$w^\ast B A v = (\tilde{A}^Bw)^\ast B v = w^\ast \left(\tilde{A}^B\right)^\ast B v.$$

For that to hold for all $v,w$, the matrices in the middle must be the same,

$$BA = \left(\tilde{A}^B\right)^\ast B \iff BAB^{-1} = \left(\tilde{A}^B\right)^\ast \iff \tilde{A}^B = (BAB^{-1})^\ast = B^{-1} A^\ast B.$$

The $B$-adjoint matrix is in general **not** the conjugate transpose.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I am surprised that the same mistake appears in several books. For example in http://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Functional-Analysis-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387855289/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1381541003&sr=8-1&keywords=barbara+maccluer  on page 35. Can you recommend any good reliable books on this topic? Also when is the matrix B a diagonal matrix and when is not? Thank you

Comment: @epsilon Can't see page 35 of that. But I have a theory. If you consider an endomorphism $f$ and its adjoint, then the matrix of $f^\ast$ _with respect to an orthonormal basis_ $\mathcal{F}$ is the conjugate transpose of the matrix of $f$ with repsect to $\mathcal{F}$. But then the matrix $B$ of the inner product with respect to the basis $\mathcal{F}$ is the identity matrix. I suspect that is stated in the linked book, but it's not stated so in the PDF.

Comment: Daniel, I haven't seen that stated in that book. That's why I was asking for a recommendation for another book. As you do, I believe that with respect to an orthonormal basis the matrix B has to be the identity so the adjoint of the transformation is the conjugate transpose of the matrix giving the transformation.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any books on linear algebra (where that rightly belongs). The books on Functional Analysis that I'm more or less familiar with all assume the reader to be familiar with that, hence don't go into it. I _think_ Lang has a book on linear algebra, that would then most likely be a good one, but of course only if you appreciate Lang's style.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true; other people have explained the reasoning, you have to take the adjoint relative to $B$. Here's an example:

$$
B = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{array}\right), A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)
$$

$B$ is Hermitian positive definite, but

$$
\left<Ax,y\right> = y^*BAx = y^*\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)x\\
\left<x,A^*y\right> = y^*ABx = y^*\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)x\\
$$
and it's not hard to find $x,y$ so that these aren't equal ($x = y = (1,0)^T$ e.g.).

Comment: Thank you BaronVT. I thought the matrix B was always diagonal. When is B diagonal and when it's not? Thank you

Comment: You can induce an inner product with any Hermitian, positive-definite matrix. Obviously, diagonal positive-definite is sufficient (i.e. a diagonal matrix with positive entries), but not necessary. 

But even in this case, diagonal matrices $B$ *will not* commute with arbitrary $A$ (unless $B = cI$), and so the adjoint still has to be taken relative to $B$.